# React with web sockets causing expensive re rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Problem** :-- I am using web socket stream to pushing data from server to client every seconds. As client is receiving every second and it is causing lots of re rendering.

**Additional** **Info** -- I am using react-redux version 7.0.2. Components are receiving data by using `mapStateToProps` method of connect API.

**Question** :-- What is the best way to reduce this extra re rendering ? Should I put comparison logic in reducer to check if anything gets change then provide a new modified state else return same. If not in reducer what would be the best way to achieve it? If you could provide any method from any library, would be great to have an example with it.

Please let me know if any extra needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use socket.io redux middlewares to be able to update the application states.

I suggest to use these:

[socket.io-emitter-middleware](https://github.com/epavanello/socket.io-emitter-middleware)

[socket.io-subscriber-middleware](https://github.com/epavanello/socket.io-subscriber-middleware)

Then I suggest to use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) library to prevent extra rendering.